# Android Child Classes and Separate Java Files

Tags: android, class, file

I am making an application for android which could grow somewhat large over time. What I would like to do is implement into the main class sub files for logic. For example:

The main activity uses a surfaceview.

```
class Battle extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {
```

I want to add all logic related to touch events in a file called touchActions.java

```
public class touchActions extends Battle {
```

It appears to work fine with no errors in Eclipse. But when I try to run it on my phone, I get a null pointer exception for the following line.

```
if (_touch.checkHitBox(1)) {
```

_touch being initiated after the Battle class is declared.

```
public touchActions _touch;
```

What is the proper way to do this, or what could be causing the nullpointerexception?

EDIT:

The goal here is organization of code, so that I don't end up with one gigantic file of code. Can I make an inner class while still using a different file? If you know of a tutorial, that would be great too.

Comment: There is not enough code here to see where the issue is.  Where are you initializing the "touchActions" member variable?

Comment: Why do you make `touchActions` a subclass of `Battle`? It should be designed to do its own thing. If it needs access to instance variables of `Battle`, consider passing `Battle`'s `this` to the `touchActions` object, or making the `touchActions` class an inner class of `Battle`. (Extending `Battle` means that a `touchActions` object will have it's own _separate and independent_ copy of all fields found in a `Battle` object.

Comment: if `public touchActions _touch;` is declared in Battle class it is huge design flaw

Comment: Ted Hopp, what would be the best way to do this? I just want to organize code into multiple files for the surfaceview.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> _touch being initiated after the Battle class is declared.
>
> public touchActions _touch;

**not initiated** ... just **declared** u need to initiatie it with something like this

```
_touch = new touchActions();
```

EDIT:

if public touchActions _touch; is declared in Battle class you do it all wrong ...

it should be something like this

```
class Battle extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {
   public touchActions _touch;
   public Battle (){
     _touch = new touchActions(this);
     _touch.callingMethodFromTouch();
   }
}

//should not extends Battle
public class touchActions {
  Battle parent_;
  public touchActions (Battle parent){
     parent_ = parent;
  }

  .... rest of implemetation you can call parent_.methodFromBattleClass(); here
}
```

Comment: i didn't read @Ted Hopp comment before i did edit, but this is exacly what he wrote